# Auto download new package in golang module project

Tags: go

I am following a golang book (using go 1.15) which not surprisingly advocates using go modules for dependency management. I have no problem following along until a chapter where it says "because we have module enabled for our project, after adding a new import to our code, we can just do `go run` and go is clever enough to notice the new import and will auto download the package as well as update the `go.mod` file for us. We don't need to manually do `go get`". In book, it appears that this auto download does work as there is screenshot in the book showing the download message.

**To clarify, this new import is added for the first time to the project.**

This is totally new to me and got me excited but when I tried it, it doesn't work. It says `no required module provides package github.com/xxx/yyy; to add it: go get github.com/xxx/yyy`;
I obviously have module enabled for the project.

Is there any setting I missed to enable this auto download?
I am using go 1.16

Comment: Go modules and how e.g. go get and go install work changes over time probably our book is just outdated. I'm not aware of some kind of "auto adding dependencies". Note that _downloading_ a added dependency happens automatically.

Comment: What is wrong with this question that people want to close it?

Comment: @Volker how do you mean "downloading an added dependency happens automatically"? Do you mean you add a new import and then run go get?

Comment: "add a new import and then run go get". Yes, this is the way to add a dependency.

Comment: Thanks @Volker I just manually run go get for the new import and it adds the dependency fine. The auto download part described in the book got me curious though hence the asking. At least now I can continue with the book.

Comment: The (semi-)automated way is to run `go mod tidy`. It will download all required dependencies (it also minimizes the dependencies by removing those `go.mod` lists but your project doesn't use).

Comment: @icza yeah I heard someone saying that. But the book I am reading is highly rated and I am sure the author wrote that for a reason. I also doubt it's due to my go version being slightly different from the book's go version. Will try to reach out to the author.

Comment: @stt106 That book was written when Go 1.14 or 1.15 was mainstream. Those versions are not even supported anymore. This behavior was changed in [Go 1.16](https://go.dev/doc/go1.16): _"Build commands like `go build` and `go test` no longer modify `go.mod` and `go.sum` by default. Instead, they report an error if a module requirement or checksum needs to be added or updated (as if the `-mod=readonly` flag were used). Module requirements and sums may be adjusted with `go mod tidy` or `go get`."_